# Unable to Change Permission for File on External Disc on Mac

Tags: macos, file, terminal, chmod, chown

## Problem

I have a corrupt file on a network NAS:

```
/bad/bad_file.file
```

Which I want to remove but I cannot. The file name is extremely long, so this may be part of the problem.

### Finder

The file has the permission `user:Read&Write, everyone:No Access`

If I try to change it with in macs file info, it basically tells me that the file is not found:

```
An unexpected error occurred (error code -43).
```

### Terminal

If cd to the folder containing the bad file's folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 bad
```

I get

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on bad_file.file
```

If I want to make myself the owner of the file:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) bad
```

I get the error:

```
chown: bad_file.file No such file or directory
```

## Question

How can I remove this file, or if it is not there make it disappear under the path in case it's not there?

Comment: Have you restarted your Mac and then see if you can remove the file ?

Comment: Yes, the Mac and the NAS and I cannot remove it.

Comment: You need to do that at the NAS level, not over the network, through SMB (or AFP), from your Mac. Login as admin on your NAS, through SSH or with its web interface, and do it there.